# How can I check if a string EXACTLY matches a regex pattern?

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a registration script for my client's product sales website.

I'm currently working on a reference ID input area, and I want to make sure that the reference ID is within the correct parameters of the payment method

The Reference ID will look something like this: `XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX`

I'm trying to use this RegEx pattern to match it: `/(\w+){5}-(\w+){5}-(\w+){5}/`

This matches it perfectly, but it also matches `XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX`

Or at least it finds a match in there. I want it to make sure the entire string matches. I'm not too familiar with RegEx

How can I do this?

Comment: Also check out the tools list in [Is there anything like RegexBuddy in the open source world?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world)

Comment: Doesn't (\w+){5} effectively mean 5 or more? Wouldn't \w{5} match correctly?

Comment: @Emyr - yes, and almost no-one else spotted that.

Comment: Ah thanks, Emyr. That's why these weren't working!

Comment: Wish I'd posted that as an answer now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use start and finish anchors. Alternatively, if you don't need to capture those groups, you can omit the parenthesis.

Also, the `+{5}` means match more than once exactly 5 times. I believe you didn't want that so I dropped the `+`.

```
/^\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}\z/
```

Also, I used `\z` so your string doesn't match `"abcde-12345-edcba\n"`.

Comment: @Sjoerd In case the string ends with a line break.

Comment: PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 6 in /root/regex.php on line 3

Comment: @Rob Enjoy! Don't forget if you want to learn more about regular expressions, http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a great site.

Comment: Don't need to use `\z` unless multi-line mode is on. When multi-line mode is off, the `$` matches only at the end-of-string.

Comment: @ridgerunner Thanks for that. I [tried it](http://ideone.com/qXJlt) but it didn't work, did I miss anything?

Comment: @ridgerunner [Here is another example](http://ideone.com/gpt5X), *without* multiline mode on. You can see the `$` matches at `\n`, *not* at the end of string exclusively. Also, *"[$] also matches before the very last line break if the string ends with a line break."* [Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Comment: @alex: You are correct sir! With PCRE, the `$` does indeed match before a newline at the end of a string with multi-line mode off (although it will not match before any other newline). I'm definitely "going to school" on this one. Thank you very much! +1

Comment: The link to ideone leads to a blank page - is the code available anywhere else?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I don't know what happened to that link. The regex is in the answer, so just drop it into the `preg_*()` appropriate function.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`^` and `$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to match the start and end of the input string, respectively.

Also note that your use of `+` was superfluous, as `(\w+){5}` means "a word character, at least once, times five" which means it can match *at least* five times. You probably meant `(\w){5}` (or just `\w{5}` if you don't need the backreference; I'll assume in my example that you do).

```
/^(\w){5}-(\w){5}-(\w){5}$/
```

Comment: you can also use `\A` and `\Z` instead of `^` and `$`

Comment: @Bob: True, and they're also subtly different in that they never match at line breaks. That may be desirable in some cases, but I can't see that it'll make a difference here.

Comment: @Alnitak: Ah, dammit! Can I have my point back, now that I fixed it? Downvoting is a bit much, though I wouldn't have expected an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

put the regular expression in between `^` and `$` to match the whole string and check if it matches anything

example:

```
/^(\w+){5}-(\w+){5}-(\w+){5}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/^([\w]{5,5})-([\w]{5,5})-([\w]{5,5})$/i
```

There are several online regex tester out there, I work with [this one](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php) before I code.

Comment: +1 for fixing the (\w+){5}, although this is far too verbose!

Answer (score 0):

Use ^ and $ to mark the start and end of the regex string:

```
/^\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}$/
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: -1 You need to put the delimiters on the _outside_ of the expression. They _delimit_ the expression. You have put the anchors outside of the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose it in "^" and "$" thus:

```
/^(\w+){5}-(\w+){5}-(\w+){5}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

`/^(\w){5}-(\w){5}-(\w){5}$/`
You need to explicitly say that you want the pattern to start at the beginning of the string and end at it's ending.
You can improve it:  `/^((\w){5}-){2}(\w){5}$/` ; this way, you can easily modify the number of elements your serial number might have.

Answer (score 0):

You need `^` to match the start of the string and `$` to match the end:

```
/^\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}$/
```

Note that `(\w+){5}` is incorrect because that means five repetitions of `\w+`, but that in turn means "one *or more* word characters".

Comment: Don't be so conspiracy theory. Nobody "tactically downvoted" you.

Comment: Someone downvoted this even though it was completely correct. maybe it was just a revenge vote?

Answer (score -1):

In preg, \b marks word boundaries. So you could try with something like

```
/\b(\w+){5}-(\w+){5}-(\w+){5}\b/
```