# Regex for 2 letters followed by 4 digits

Tags: php, regex

The string should begin with "S2" followed by any 4 digits.

A matching string is "S20165".

I'm trying with the following code, but it always echos OK even when there are 5 or 6 digits.

```
$string='S20104';
if(preg_match('/S2[0-9]{4}/', $string)){
    echo 'OK';
}
else{
    echo 'NOT OK';
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a string EXACTLY matches a regex pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596346/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-exactly-matches-a-regex-pattern)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use anchors:

```
/^S2[0-9]{4}$/
```

`^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end of the string, so this will make sure that you check the complete string and not just a substring.

You can also use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. In PHP, as long as you do not use the 'u' [pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), preg* functions are not Unicode aware, so the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that preg_match searches for a match *anywhere* inside the string.

```
S2123456
^^^^^^
matches
```

You can anchor your regular expression using `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line):

```
'/^S2[0-9]{4}$/'
```

- See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/5uXl6)
- Read more about anchors: [regularexpresssions.info/anchors.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: The anchor needs to be a character to the left :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$string='S20104';
if(preg_match('/^S2[0-9]{4}$/', $string)){
    echo 'OK';
}
else{
    echo 'NOT OK';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the start and end of the string too

```
/^S2[0-9]{4}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed the start^ and end$

```
'/^S2[0-9]{4}$/'
```