# How can i !preg-match a student id

Tags: php, html

I need to make a validation for a student id input on my form how can I make it have a format like "A12345678" having a letter followed by 8 numbers

Comment: What have you tried? Have you made any attempt of solving this yourself?
 Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In this `A12345678` there are 8 numbers.

Comment: try this `preg_match('/^A\d{7}$/','A1234567');`

Answer (score -1):

Add your validation in the input form like this
 
 
<
input type='text' id="student_id" name="student_id" pattern="[A-Z,a-z]{1}[0-9]{8}" title="Enter Correct Student ID" class="form-control" required>

in pattern : 
[A-Z,a-z]{1} means 1 character is Alphabetic(upper or lower case)

[0-9]{8} means 8 characters are numeric

Hope it helps!!

Comment: This doesn't help with the back end validation, which the OP asked about. Even if you have this in the form, you should _always_ validate the data in the back end as well. _Never_ trust data that comes from users.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson maybe this can help <br> :preg_match('/[a-z]\d{1,8}/','A12345678');

Comment: Are you asking me to debug your answer for you?

Comment: Just trying to help. however just got some similar questions with answers                   : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296056/regex-for-2-letters-followed-by-4-digits AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512890/php-preg-match-item-first-five-character-regex

Comment: I know that you are, but you should (just like the OP should) test it yourself first.